# How to retrieve the list of Email IDs using Pardot API?

Tags: rest-api, pardot

I'm planning to use Email Statistics (https://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-4/emails/#email-statistics) but it requires the **Pardot ID of the Email**. I checked the documentation of Email (https://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-4/emails/) but can't find an entry on how to get the list of IDs. Is it possible to get the IDs, and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

The Pardot API is not great in this area. You are correct that there is no way for an external system to query/get a list of emails directly.

You could query VisitorActivity for email sends and iterate the records looking for unique Email IDs that way, though it's a terribly not-efficient way to tackle the challenge.

Another approach which is even more brittle is to use a UI automation test tool (Selenium / Cypress) to screen scrape Pardot looking for IDs (we do this today for our comprehensive Pardot audits).  Works good enough, though I wouldn't build a rock-solid production level codebase on it.

A manual approach could be to have Pardot Users grab the Email ID of any emails they want tracked with your statistics and load them up somewhere.

Comment: Yeah. I noticed that the VisitorActivity is the only endpoint that returns the Email IDs.

Option #2 won't do since my app can only connect via the API.